# How to translate Java HMAC to Node/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, sha256, hmac

I am trying to implement an HMAC signature in node from the vendor's provided Java example (their documentation was quite lacking, not detailing encodings, or requirements).

The vendor's provided Java code:

```java
// encrypt strToSign by SHA algorithm
var signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(clientSecret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
var mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
mac.init(signingKey);
signedStr = bytesToHexString(mac.doFinal(strToSign.getBytes()));

function bytesToHexString(bytes) {
  if (bytes == null) {
    return null;
  }
  sb = "";
  for (var b of bytes) {
    var hv = String.format("%02x", b);
    sb += hv;
  }
  return sb.toLowerCase();
}
```

My JavaScript code:

```js
var signedStr = crypto
  .createHmac('SHA256', Buffer.from(clientSecret, "utf8"))
  .update(strToSign, "utf8")
  .digest('hex');
```

Getting a an error: `msg: 'Signature does not match'` result from the server. I have tried almost every combination I can think of changing the encoding of the client secret and `strToSign`.

I usually can figure out how to get my problems fixed with a quick search. And I feel extremely close. However now I am at a nexus wherein I cannot quite determine what nuances between the provided Java code and my attempt at a Node translation. I feel that it is going to be related to encoding, off by one, or big endian type issue. Unfortunately with hash/signatures I cannot just brute force my way to an answer (I have tried).

Comment: Is the vendor's code actually Java, looks more like JS to me... aside from the `String.format` call.

Comment: To add clarification, the clientSecret provided to me is a 32 character string. It is in hexadecimal, but reading the vendor's implementation makes me assume we want the utf8 of the 32 characters anyway(Java.String.getBytes()). I am assuming that there is going to be a slight difference in how java handles the strings.
The vendor provided Java code only. I tried to translate it as best as i could
https://pastebin.com/X2zws2JL

Comment: Why are you posting such messed up Java code in the question instead of the actual one you reference in the comment? Please fix the code in the question. Apart from that, Java code and NodeJS code you posted return the same HMAC for identical input data. So if you get different results, your input data is different. If the verification fails at the server, either the input data is wrong or the logic of the Java code does not match that implemented in the server. In any case, this question lacks the information to answer this.

Comment: I did not want to add unnecessary information to the question. and included everything needed to answer the question I had(was i missing an encoding issue in the translation to node code), as you mentioned the answer was indeed that the data being fed was different. There was an undocumented expectation to strip hostname and params from the requestURL. 
I want to leave the question here as how to directly translate that Java HMAC integration into Node.

Comment: The code following *The vendor's provided Java code* is not valid Java, as already stated in the first comment. In contrast, the code you linked yourself contains valid Java code. Why don't you fix the invalid Java code in your question? Posting a link is not enough. Fixing an invalid code is not *unnecessary information*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inputs are already strings, you can encode them directly.

```js
import { Buffer } from "node:buffer";
import crypto from "node:crypto";

const encode = (secret, data) => {
  // Not needed, as string defaults to 'utf8'
  const encoding =
    typeof secret === "string"
      ? { encoding: "utf8" }
      : undefined;
  return crypto
    .createHmac("sha256", secret, encoding)
    .update(data) // If data is a string, default to 'utf8'
    .digest("hex");
};

// String
const clientSecret = "client-secret";
const strToSign = "string-to-sign";
console.log(encode(clientSecret, strToSign));

// Buffer
const secretBuffer = Buffer.from(clientSecret, "utf8");
const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(strToSign, "utf8");
console.log(encode(secretBuffer, dataBuffer));
```

Both calls log `7c13c6e89d4402cf331c7b0cb6a16b98f04144a247f796e6afaaae1cff64af0d`